# Communication with android Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm developing an android application which creates an android service which refresh the location of the mobile device using gps. It works with a timer that in 'x' time, it refresh the position.

The problem is that I would like to comunicate with that local android service from one activity of the application, because I would like to change the refresh time ('x') when I want. So, How do I can do it?

One possible solution is to stop the service and then start again every time the time refresh is changed, but I think it is not the optimal solution.

Any suggerence, help, pls?

Answer (score 3):

If you are within the same Process-Space (Same Application/.apk) you can just establish a simple Service Connection
In your activity, include something like the following:

```
private ServiceConnection _svcConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        _myService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        _myService = ((MyService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if(!_myService.IsRunning())
            _myService.Start();
    }
};

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    bindService(new Intent(Main.this, MyService.class), _svcConnection 
            BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(new Intent(Main.this, MyService.class));
    super.onResume();
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    unbindService(_svcConnection);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Your Service needs a binder:

```
    private final IBinder _Binder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return _Binder;
}

/**
 * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
 * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

Then you can work with the _MyService object and call any Method on it. (E. g. Registering a Callback or request Location Updates), but be aware that if the service connection fails, the _MyService variable will be null!

```
_MyService.SetInterval(4);
```

If you need to access this service from another Application (Another Process), you have to deal with IPC.

Comment: I dont understand all the code. I have some questions: If the activity that binds the service dies, or is paused, etc, then onResume restarts it?

Comment: For activity livecycle please refer to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). If an activity is started by intent, or resumed from background or a user invoked it, OnResume is called. In that Method, a binding to the Service is requested (bindService), and if the service is currently not running, we ask the android system to start it for us (e. g. first application start). OnPause just unbinds the service from the activity, to avoid memory leaking. If the service does not stop itself or is killed by the system, it will continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you, You do this in service, it will refresh your location in this method

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Refresh Time");
      timer.schedule(RefreshTask, 1000L, 60 * 1000L);
private TimerTask refreshTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() { 
                 Log.i(TAG, "Update time here");
                            }
 };
```